# How can I use Elixir's doctest to test a protocol implementation?

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I want to be able to [doctest](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/master/ExUnit.DocTest.html) the *implementation* of a [protocol](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html) in Elixir.

Here is some example code:

```
defprotocol Size do
  def size(data)
end

defmodule Foo do
  defstruct []

  defimpl Size do
    @doc """

    ## Examples

        iex> Size.size(%Foo{})
        0
    """
    def size(foo) do
      0
    end
  end
end
```

This test code doesn't work (because it only finds functions defined in the `Foo` module, outside of the `defimpl`):

```
ExUnit.start()

defmodule FooTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest Foo
end
```

How can I test the `defimpl` block?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that `defimpl` defines a module behind the scenes. This can be found via the `impl_for` function on the protocol:

```
iex(1)> Size.impl_for(%Foo{})
Size.Foo
```

So we can doctest this module like so:

```
defmodule FooTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest Foo
  doctest Size.Foo
end
```

Note that if both `Size` and `Foo` are in the same module (say `MyModule`), the module name must be specified twice:

```
defmodule FooTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest MyModule.Foo
  doctest MyModule.Size.MyModule.Foo
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the name of the protocol in front of the path.
For the given example, it would be:

```
defmodule FooTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest Foo
  doctest Size.Foo
end
```

For the longer example, it's just:

```
defmodule FooTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest MyModule.Foo
  doctest Size.MyModule.Foo
end
```

Per Valim: [https://groups.google.com/g/elixir-lang-talk/c/zNMFKOA-I7c](https://%20%20https://groups.google.com/g/elixir-lang-talk/c/zNMFKOA-I7c)